# Postgres Return just the first occurrence based on a not unique column

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I know this question has been asked several times now but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I'm using node-postgres to get data from a database which has lots of duplicated data.
This is the query i'm using but it still returns duplicates:

```
var queryText = 'SELECT distinct on(kodartikulli)  grupi, kodifikimartikulli2, pershkrimartikulli FROM products WHERE kodartikulli IN (' + params.join(',') + ')';
```

This is the result:

```
[ anonymous {
    grupi: 'Syze Dielli',
    kodifikimartikulli2: 'Polar',
    pershkrimartikulli: 'POLAR 556 03' } ]
[ anonymous {
    grupi: 'Syze Dielli',
    kodifikimartikulli2: 'Polar',
    pershkrimartikulli: 'POLAR 556 03' },
  anonymous {
    grupi: 'Syze Dielli',
    kodifikimartikulli2: 'Polar',
    pershkrimartikulli: 'POLAR 558 01' } ]
```

As you can see the first two results are identical. I just want to return one of them and continue with the second like this:

```
[ anonymous {
    grupi: 'Syze Dielli',
    kodifikimartikulli2: 'Polar',
    pershkrimartikulli: 'POLAR 556 03' } ],
  anonymous {
    grupi: 'Syze Dielli',
    kodifikimartikulli2: 'Polar',
    pershkrimartikulli: 'POLAR 558 01' } ]
```

Comment: There was a mistake in my code. Now it's displaying data as it should. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT distinct on(kodartikulli) grupi, kodifikimartikulli2, pershkrimartikulli
FROM products
WHERE kodartikulli IN (' + params.join(',') + ')' + '
ORDER BY kodartikulli;
```

This will return an arbitrary row for each `kodartikulli`.  Normally, there is an additional key specifying which of the rows to return.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: @joop . . . No.  With `distinct on`, you want to use `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting records with distinct `kodartikulli`. You should show us your source data, but surely the kodartikulli is different for the 2 records, that's why both of them are extracted.